# Combining XPath selectors to select descendant or self

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following XPath selectors:

```
//*[text()="Surname"]//parent::*//following-sibling::*[self::select or self::input or self::textarea]
//*[text()="Surname"]//parent::*//following-sibling::*//*[self::select or self::input or self::textarea]
```

To select an input, select or textarea from the label in either this structure:

```
    <div>
      <div><label for="">Surname</label></div>
      <div class="help">Some help text in a tooltip</div>
      <div class="control">
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

or this one:

```
    <div>
      <div><label for="">Surname</label></div>
      <div class="help">Some help text in a tooltip</div>
      <input type="text" value="" />
    </div>
```

This works fine however, just focusing on the end of the selectors, I was wondering **is it possible to make this just one selector?**

I've tried descendant-or-self instead of self on the 2nd selector above but it doesn't work selecting the 2nd dom structure.

Comment: Which browser are you using alex?

Comment: I am still not sure why you are unable to `select an input` where the `<input type="text" name="test2" value="" id="test2" />` clearly have an `id="test2"`. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry my example is awful. I'll remove all the hooks now.

Comment: Using Chrome. Actually the first selector satisfies both

Answer (score 1):

You can go two levels up and look for any descendant

```
//*[text()="Surname"]//..//..//*[self::select or self::input or self::textarea]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following XPath identifies the `div` element that contain the `label` element with the "Surname" value, then uses the `following-sibling::` axis to match any of the elements at the same level that come after that matched `div` (it could be the form elements from the second example or div that contain those form elements from the first example), then uses the `descendant-or-self::` axis with a predicate to match any of the desired form elements.

```
//div[label = 'Surname']
  /following-sibling::*
    /descendant-or-self::*[self::select or self::input or self::textarea]
```

Comment: out of interest, why the single slash and not the double. The single means from the root, no?

Comment: An XPath that begins with a single slash will "jump up" to the root node. However, from the middle of an XPath the double slash is shorthand for `descendant::` axis and will look for a match at any level from the context node. In the XPath that I provided, the following-sibling could be the item we want to match. I wanted to match descendants OR the context node, so needed a single slash and then used `descendant-or-self::` axis. http://homepage.cs.latrobe.edu.au/mjsutherland/WS/current/notes/lecture070_XSL_010/xpathAxis.png

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Try opening your HTML/Page in browser.
2. Press F12 or right-click and press "Inspect element" on
   browser.
3. Try to search for the element you need suppose `<input>`
   element.
4. Right-click on that element, select "Copy" and then select
   "Copy selector".
5. To verify whether the selector is giving you the correct
   element in your case `<input>` element. Open Console of your browser
   and type `$("")`
   Now, just paste the element you copied in between the quotes and
   press enter. You should see the html of `<input>` element.
6. After successful verification in your Selenium code use
   `ByCSSSelector` and paste the thing which you copied and pasted in
   quotes in Step 5.

Run the program successfully.

Comment: Thanks @Ashraf.Shk786 I get how to verify it. It was more about capturing what I was after in 1 selector.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this wasn't working before but the first selector actually covers both cases now. I just realised `parent::*` can be `..` too

```
//*[text()="Surname"]//..//following-sibling::*[self::select or self::input or self::textarea]
```